# Connect to Mongo Shell on OpenShift

Tags: mongodb

I have a gear running a instance of mongoDB. I wish to connect to the mongo shell. How can I do it?

I have rhc and mongoDB installed on my computer.

I have RockMongo on the gear, but I cannot create a geospatial index from RockMongo.

I used **rhc port-forward** whic didn't give any error.

and then tried to connect using the following.

```
mongo -u<your mongodb user name> -p<the password for mongoDB>  --host <the ip number for mongoDB> --port <the port number> <app name>
```

for host I used the localhost address because I have port forward running. Now I can connect but every command i use results in `"errmsg" : "unauthorised"`

Answer (score 1):

### Work Arround

I used [**PuTTY to connect to the gear**](https://www.openshift.com/developers/install-and-setup-putty-ssh-client-for-windows) and form there I could connect to the mongo shell, and thus  solved the issue.

Some Articles that might be helpfull to others.

- [**Remote Access to Your Application.**](https://www.openshift.com/developers/remote-access)
- [**connecting-to-mongodb-gear-using-your-local-mongo-client-and-rhc-port-forwarding.**](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/connecting-to-mongodb-gear-using-your-local-mongo-client-and-rhc-port-forwarding)